# SQL Server: force Backup/Restore location

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Took a copy of a database of SQL Server Express on a laptop using the `BACKUP DATABASE` command, now I'm trying to restore it to a different computer using the T-SQL statement:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [OurDB]
FROM DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part1.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part2.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part3.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part4.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part5.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part6.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part7.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part8.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part9.bak',
DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part10.bak'
WITH REPLACE
GO
```

But when it tries to restore I get the error

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Directory lookup for the file "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\AppConfig_Data.ndf" failed with the
>   operating system error 3 (failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 1815).

And a couple of others, all similar errors. The problem is it looks like SQL Server is trying to restore the database to the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\`, the data directory on the source computer the backup was taken from.

But on the new computer I want to restore to the SQL Server data path is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA`

How do I change the path in the data-files to get it to restore to the correct location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add additional info to your RESTORE command to define where those bits should go - something like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [OurDB]
FROM DISK = N'C:\Documents and Settings\Sam\Desktop\DBBackup\part1.bak',
MOVE N'Your_Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\OurDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'Your_Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\OurDB_Log.ldf'
```